# Send request failed in terraform with x509 signed by unknown authority

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform , when i try to run terraform plan i am getting an send request failed.
How can i solve this?

```
* RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://sts.amazonaws.com/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Terraform v0.8.7
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you show more details about what terraform code you're running that's throwing this error?

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10779

Comment: Terraform Enterprise may be configured with TLS certificates that are not publicly-trusted.
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046090994-Terraform-runs-failing-with-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error
& If you are facing in Mac, try the below approach:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22193#issuecomment-610877715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [solution proposed on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10779#issuecomment-304664405):

> In my case it was an issue with my SSL certs that curl was using. I fixed it by setting CURL_CA_BUNDLE to a copy of this [file](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)*, locally.

```
* https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
```